# Why does the InstanceID service automatically start and how do I preven this?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android application where I'm using GCM.  I'm following the tutorials and using an `InstanceIDListenerService` class which I'm attempting to fire off as an `IntentService` after a "subscription" page where the user enters some information.  There is also some preliminary code firing off prior to this subscription page on a splash screen behind the scenes.  The `InstanceIDListenerService` constructor is being called (and subsequently, the onHandleIntent) in the SplashScreen activity before I even get to the SubscriptionActivity.  Why is it doing this? Is it possible for an intent service to start on it's own?

I do have the service registered in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, and when I comment out the following lines, it does not trigger the instance to get created automatically, the app works as intended (until I need to use the instance of course...)

```
<service
    android:name=".service.receiver.InstanceIDListenerService"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**SplashScreen.java**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver dbInsertReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if(bundle != null) {
                // Handle results and move to next activity, should
                // be the subscribe activity where I want the instance 
                // id listener to start.
            }
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver providerXMLReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
             if(bundle != null) {
                 // Handle results and start the next service                 
             }
         }
     }
 };

    /** Called when the activity is first created */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        // Kick off the service download to update the provider data
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProviderDataService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(providerXMLReceiver, new IntentFilter(ProviderDataService.CHANNEL));
        registerReceiver(dbInsertReceiver, new IntentFilter(InternalDBService.NOTIFICATION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(providerXMLReceiver, new IntentFilter(ProviderDataService.CHANNEL));
    registerReceiver(dbInsertReceiver, new IntentFilter(InternalDBService.NOTIFICATION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(providerXMLReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(dbInsertReceiver);
    }            

    private void moveToNextActivity(int subscriptionStatus) {
        if(subscriptionStatus == DBSchemaHelper.IS_SUBSCRIBED_NOT_RESPONDED) {
            Intent subscribeIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, SubscribeActivity.class);
            startActivity(subscribeIntent);
        } else {
            // Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity.
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }

        this.finish();
    }
```

**SubscribeActivity.java**

```
public class SubscribeActivity extends CustomActionBarActivity {

    public static final int NO_SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS = -99;
    private DBMetaDataSource metaDao;
    private int subscribeResult;

    public SubscribeActivity() {
        metaDao = new DBMetaDataSource(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscribe);
    }    

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(tokenResponseReceiver, new IntentFilter(InstanceIDListenerService.TAG));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(tokenResponseReceiver, new IntentFilter(InstanceIDListenerService.TAG));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(tokenResponseReceiver);
    }

    public void subscribeUser(View v) {
        EditText emailTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subscriptionUserEmail);
        String email = emailTextView.getText().toString();

        // This is the only place I am manually starting this service.
        // I have set a breakpoint here, but I never hit it and the service
        // starts on its own and I hit the breakpoints in the service's 
        // onHandleIntent method.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, InstanceIDListenerService.class);
        i.putExtra("email", email);
        startService(i);
    }

    public void goToNextActivity(View v) {
        // They pressed the button to NOT subscribe, so we are calling this from the
        // view rather than the intent receiver, meaning the view will not be null.
        if(v != null) {
            markUnsubscribed();
        }

        /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SubscribeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.SUBSCRIBE_STATUS_KEY, subscribeResult);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }

    private void markUnsubscribed() {
        metaDao.open(this);
        DBMeta metaData = metaDao.get();
        metaDao.update(Long.valueOf(metaData.getVersion()), metaData.getLastRunInMillis(), DBSchemaHelper.IS_SUBSCRIBED_RESPONDED_NO, null);
        metaDao.close();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver tokenResponseReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            subscribeResult = intent.getIntExtra(InstanceIDListenerService.RESPONSE_KEY, NO_SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS);
            goToNextActivity(null);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be starting a `InstanceIDListenerService` yourself - that is for the system to call *you* when you need to refresh your Instance ID tokens via a callback to [onTokenRefresh()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceIDListenerService#onTokenRefresh()) - if you haven't created any instance id tokens yet, then you'd just have no work to do on that first call.

If you have other work to do, you should use your own service.

Comment: So a first time user wants to subscribe to push notifications, I would need to call the `instanceID.getToken` method in my own service for that initial sign up, then implement the listener service for subsequent checks to/from the app server?

Comment: @akousmata - correct, you'd call `InstanceID.getToken()` anywhere off your main thread (whether it is a service, `AsyncTask`, etc), store the returned token locally and send it to your server. Then whenever `onTokenRefresh()` is called, you'd call `InstanceID.getToken()` again, get a new token, and send *that* up to the server (probably including the old token as well so your server can remove it, replacing it with the new one).