# Not getting refreshed token firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have trouble in getting refreshed token in firebase. I have gone through documentation and followed the steps fro android exactly. In my log I find firebase connection as successful. Not sure why I am not getting the instance token. I am in initial stage and trying to get the token in logcat.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.project.application"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ProjectName"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"> 

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>       
    </application>

</manifest>

    public class MyInstanceIDListenerService  extends FirebaseInstanceIdService{    
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    }

 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    String messageBody = null;

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    sendNotification(messageBody);

}
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: token only generate only once. you need to clear your app data to get new push token.

Comment: I have not got even once  if I have understood you correctly. I followed the steps in firebase andriod and I was expecting the token in log.But I am not able to see this Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken) at all. I should get atleast the log with "Refreshed token" . But there is no record in log for this.

Comment: did u start the service with `startService(new Intent(this, MyFirebaseMessagingService .class));`

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez : no I have not tarted it. Doesn't it automatically start? Referred here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671345/why-does-the-instanceid-service-automatically-start-and-how-do-i-preven-this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `onTokenRefresh()` method doesn't trigger the first time an app Is installed. It is only triggered by [specific scenarios](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService#onTokenRefresh()).

To get your token, you have to call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` at the start of your app (like in `onCreate` or something).

Comment: I am getting token if I do in create. But still not getting the notifictaion message from firebase console.

Comment: @jenny Can you post your Android side code for receiving the message?

Comment: I have updated my Messaging service code. I am still unable to get a notification in mobile though I get in log.

Answer (score 2):

From the github project of `FCM` [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java#L35-L45)

The documentation `onTokenRefresh()` reads :

> - Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of       the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.

You have to `Clear Cache` of you app or reinstall it in order to call this method.

Answer (score 1):

fix your permission

```
<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Make sure you have correct google-service.json.

Note: token only generate once. try to clean app data to get new token

EDIT:

Or you can do iteration to get token manually in your Activity/Fragment class

```
FirebaseInstanceId iid = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance();
String token = iid.getToken();

while(token == null){
    iid = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance();
    token = iid.getToken();
}

Logger.info("TOKEN","==>"+token);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The onNewToken callback fires whenever a new token is generated.

```
/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}
```

To get your token, you have to call  call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()`

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                                    return;
                                }

                                // Get new Instance ID token
                                String token = task.getResult().getToken();

                                // Log and toast
                                String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
                                Log.d(TAG, msg);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: You might want to indicate that your answer applies to the FirebaseMessagingService class in 17.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the google-services.json file and re-adding it.